# TypeIt.js: Empty container afterComplete each string

Tags: javascript, string

Hello I started using TypeIt.js but I am having trouble with the transition between strings.

I would basically like to:

- type first string
- pause for a couple seconds
- empty, without the default deleting backwards
- type out the next string

I updated my previous post because I realised there was an issue with the version. The following code almost works but only after the second string is complete.

How can I run the empty function after EACH string?
I am trying to not have the backward deleting after the first string.

https://codepen.io/NewbCake/pen/pxqVWO

Thanks for any help.

JS

```
new TypeIt('#element', {
  strings: ['First string', 'Second string'],
  breakLines: false,
  speed: 100,
  cursor: false,
  loop: true,

  afterString: function(step, queue, instance) {
    instance.pause(1000).empty();
  },

})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the chainable instance methods to do this, but they have to be attached to the main TypeIt instance before initialization. It would look something like this:

```js
new TypeIt('#element', {
  breakLines: false,
  speed: 100,
  cursor: false,
  loop: true
})
  .type("First string.")
  .pause(1000)
  .empty()
  .type("Second string.")
  .pause(1000)
  .empty()
  .go();
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/alexmacarthur/pen/MWwwJVO

You could also pull this off using the `afterString` callback, which is now asynchronous in v6.5.0, but the code's a little weirder.

```js
new TypeIt('#element', {
  strings: ["First string.", "Second string."],
  breakLines: false,
  speed: 100,
  cursor: false,
  loop: true, 
  afterString: async (step, queue, instance) => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        instance.instances[0].$e.innerHTML = "";
        return resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}).go();
```

Hope that helps some!